# Re-using Stud hole in wall

Tags: walls, screws, hanging

I have a guitar hanger that I didn't put together tightly enough so it loosened over time, and I want to tighten it and hang it again. It was put into a stud and I was wondering if I could reuse the existing holes, possibly with just a larger diameter screw.

Comment: The _same_ screw should be fine unless it was loose to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a larger screw or a longer screw if you stripped out the original hole.

Answer (score 0):

Standard trick is to throw a few wooden matches in there and put the screw back in.

Comment: Maybe with the match head cut off, right?  I hope?

Comment: doesn't actually matter...

Answer (score 0):

Use a bigger diameter screw (1/4in)

Comment: Can you expand on this a bit?  How will a bigger screw help?